# Qt QML Notify ListView when items in the model are added or removed

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qt5

My ListView should always scroll its currently active item to the top between `preferredHighlightBegin` and `preferredHighlightEnd`. That works while clicking an item. However when a new item is added to my AbsctractListModel (And its not just added on the end but could be added anywhere in the middle), the ListView shows the new item, but it is not scrolled to the top. This is most likely because `list.currentIndex = index` is not set for new added items. I want to set it but did not find a way yet to do so. Does anyone have a hint?

I tried different signals such as `onCurrentItemChanged` but did not find the proper one yet which also gives me the correct index.

```
ListView {
    id: list
    anchors.fill: parent
    clip: true
    spacing: 11
    focus: true
    highlightMoveDuration: 400
    snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem
    preferredHighlightBegin: 0
    preferredHighlightEnd: 100
    highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange

    model: myAbstractListModel

    delegate: ListItem {
                  height: 56
                  width: list.width
                  color: "red"
                  onListItemClicked: {
                      list.currentIndex = index
                  }
              }
}
```

The expected result would be a ListView which scrolls a programmatically new added item of my AbstractListModel to the top (between `preferredHighlightBegin` and `preferredHighlightEnd`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding this to your `ListView` will change the current index to the last one whenever the number of items in the model changes, you might want to keep track of the previous items count if you want to scroll only on insertion.

```
onCountChanged: {
    if (count > 0) {
        currentIndex = count - 1;
    }
}
```

If the new items might be inserted anywhere in the model you could connect directly to it using the [Connections](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-connections.html) item inside your `ListView` and connect it directly to the [rowsInserted](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsInserted) signal of `QAbstractItemModel`.

```
Connections {
    target: model
    onRowsInserted: {
        currentIndex = first + 1;
    }
}
```

If your model emits only the `dataChanged` signal you can try this.

```
Connections {
    target: model
    onDataChanged: {
        currentIndex = topLeft.row() + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this is not working since the model has different types of items and a new added item might not be added just at the end of the list but could be added anywhere in the middle which i forgot to mention.

Comment: That's a pretty important piece of information. I've updated the answer. :)

Comment: I see it would have solved my problem, however after a tested it i realized the model does not emit a rowsInserted signal but only a dataChanged signal. Unfortunatly i do not have control over the model to implement a rowsInserted signal. Is there any chance to use the dataChanged signal for a solution?

Comment: `dataChanged` should be emitted only when existing elements are modified, not when inserting or removing elements. Nonetheless I've updated my answer.